# How do I combine these two Geometry Node trees?

Tags: shaders, geometry-nodes, geometry, shader-nodes

The goal was to make curves with round ends and also animate the "start factor" and "end". I found 2 tutorials demonstrating the same thing. There is 1 video on how to make round caps and one on how to animate them. However, I want both of them in the same node tree. Please help me

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, I tried to give this a more noticeable title

Comment: can u pls provide blend file?

Comment: sure I'll provide the file

Comment: can you provide you email so i can send it there. @Chris

Comment: Tip: you can use https://blend-exchange.com/ to share your blend file.